# Reading a website table from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, html-table

I am making an application in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) that gets data from a webpage:
http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.10.html

On that page,click the "Show all downloads" button and a table appears, I want get the data from that table, specifically only the "Version" column and then add it to a listview.
For this I use the following code:

```vb
Private Sub files()
    Dim source As String = New Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.10.html")
    Dim recentSource As String = GetTagContents(source, "<table class=""downloadsTable"" id=""downloadsTable"">", "</table>")(0)
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
    For Each title As String In GetTagContents(recentSource, "<li>", "</li>")
        If Not title.Contains("http:") Then
            lvi.Text = title
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetTagContents(ByVal Source As String, ByVal startTag As String, ByVal endTag As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim StringsFound As New List(Of String)
    Dim Index As Integer = Source.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length
    While Index <> startTag.Length - 1
        StringsFound.Add(Source.Substring(Index, Source.IndexOf(endTag, Index) - Index))
        Index = Source.IndexOf(startTag, Index) + startTag.Length
    End While
    Return StringsFound
End Function
```

The problem is that it shows only the first value in the table "10.13.4.1492".
The program does not continue with the following lines of the table, only it stays there.

Comment: Did you attempt to use functions *Step Into* and *Step Over* from Visual Studio's *Debug* menu?  Place breakpoint (also found in that menu) at line `Function GetTagContents()` and run the program. Then use *Step Into* repeatedly and watch content of your variables – hover mouse over them to inspect or add them into watches.  If you have this research done, you can update your question with findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the following code:

```
Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
For Each title As String In GetTagContents(recentSource, "<li>", "</li>")
    If Not title.Contains("http:") Then
        lvi.Text = title
        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    End If
Next
```

It only creates one ListViewItem object, before the loop. You need a new ListViewItem in each iteration:

```
For Each title As String In GetTagContents(recentSource, "<li>", "</li>")
    If Not title.Contains("http:") Then
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
        lvi.Text = title
        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    End If
Next
```

Or even better:

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange(
GetTagContents(recentSource, "<li>", "</li>").
    Where(Function(t) Not t.Contains("http:")).
    Select(Function(t) New ListViewItem(t)).
    ToArray() )
```

Ideally, you'd find an rss feed source for this data. Rss is made for this kind of scraping.